# JSONP angular js displaying multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Similar to another question i posted i'm having an issue with grabbing the weather for the week and allocating different rows. Basically the format i want is:

```
        Mon       Tues        Wed          Thurs
```

Sydney      25         21          21           22

Melbourne    26        18          21           24

etc
unfortunatly it is grabbing the first part of the array and coppying that to all areas.

Here is my js :

```
app.controller('forecastCtrl',function($scope, $http){
$scope.weatherDataSydney = null;
    $scope.weatherDataBrisbane = null;
    $scope.weatherDataPerth = null;
    $scope.weatherDataMelbourne = null;
    $scope.weatherDataAdelaide = null;
    $scope.weatherDataDarwin = null;



$http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/forecast/q/Australia/Sydney.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
     $scope.weatherDataSydney=data;


  });
     $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/forecast/q/Australia/Brisbane.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
     $scope.weatherDataBrisbane=data;

  });
     $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/forecast/q/Australia/Melbourne.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
     $scope.weatherDataMelbourne=data;
  });
     $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/forecast/q/Australia/Perth.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
     $scope.weatherDataPerth=data;
  });
      $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/forecast/q/Australia/Darwin.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
     $scope.weatherDataDarwin=data;
  });

      $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/forecast/q/Australia/Cairns.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
     $scope.weatherDataCairns=data;
  });
      $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/forecast/q/Australia/Adelaide.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
      $scope.weatherDataAdelaide=data;


     $scope.cityForecasts=[
       {  name:'Sydney',
          high: $scope.weatherDataSydney.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday
        }, 


     {  name:'Brisbane',
       high: $scope.weatherDataBrisbane.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday
        },               

      { name:'Melbourne',
      high: $scope.weatherDataMelbourne.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday

        },

     { 
        name:'Adelaide',
        high: $scope.weatherDataAdelaide.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday


      },

     {  name:'Darwin',
        high: $scope.weatherDataDarwin.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday


      },

     {  name:'Perth',
        high: $scope.weatherDataPerth.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday


     },

     {  name:'Cairns',
        high: $scope.weatherDataCairns.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday


    },
     ]

  });

    $scope.getForecast = function() {
        for( i=1; i < 2; i++){
        for(x=0;x<1;x++){
        return($scope.cityForecasts[i].high[x].high.celsius);
    }
  }



      }






});
```

Here is the html

```
<div id="forecast-container">

    <div class="forecast" ng-repeat="cityForecast in cityForecasts">
        <div class="city-forecast">
            <span>{{cityForecast.name}}</span>
        </div>  

        <div class="list-days">
            <ul class="day">
                <li id="day1">Mon</li>
                <li id="day2">Tues</li>
                <li id="day3">Wed</li>
                <li id="day4">Thur</li>


            </ul>   

        </div>
        <div class="temp-list"> 
            <ul >
                <li class="temp" ng-repeat="forecast in weatherDataSydney.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday">

                {{getForecast()}}
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues I see are:

1. where you are calling **{{ getForcast() }}** in your code
2. how **getForcast** is set up.
3. ng-repeat in your html

You can actually solve the problem directly in html (i'm assuming your object structure).

Final HTML:

```
<div id="forecast-container">
    <div class="forecast" ng-repeat="cityForecast in cityForecasts">
        <div class="city-forecast">
            <span>{{cityForecast.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-days">
            <ul class="day">
                <li id="day1">Mon</li>
                <li id="day2">Tues</li>
                <li id="day3">Wed</li>
                <li id="day4">Thur</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="temp-list"> 
            <ul >
                <li class="temp" ng-repeat="forecast in cityForecast.high">
                    {{ forecast.celsius }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Since you have cityForecast in your ng-repeat, all you would need to do is loop cityForecast.high (assuming that cityForecast.high is an array).

**Previously you had this as html:**

```
<ul >
    <li class="temp" ng-repeat="forecast in weatherDataSydney.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday">
        {{getForecast()}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

You were looping forecast only from weatherDataSydney (which still wasn't the exact issue you were seeing), but if we look at getForecast()

```
$scope.getForecast = function() {
    //only running once
    for( i=1; i < 2; i++){
        //only running once
        for(x=0;x<1;x++){
            //This would be returning the same statement (below) every single time getForecast was called
            //return($scope.cityForecasts[1].high[0].high.celsius);
            //which would always be equal to Brisbane's temp (per the code you posted)
            return($scope.cityForecasts[i].high[x].high.celsius);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you solve the issue.